# JSON Parsing Query in AS3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating an application that uses a License Plate Recognition System.

The API that I'm using is rest based and returns a JSON to my application, a JSON which I parse and which basically looks like this:

```
{"plate": 
{"data_type": "alpr_results", "epoch_time": 1469660951857, "img_height": 288, "img_width": 432, "results": 
[{"plate": "MBR527D", "confidence": 88.891518.....
```

This is what my parse looks like when I load it into Actionscript:

```
var ThePlate:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data)
```

The Issue I'm having is that I'm unable to trace the Plate entitled "MBR527D" within results, basically because I'm a noob when it comes to JSON.

This is what I try when I attempt to trace the plate and I know I'm doing something wrong:

```
trace(ThePlate.results.plate);
```

It returns "undefined", however when I try to trace the image height:

```
trace(ThePlate.img_height);
```

It returns the 288 just fine, so I know I'm making a basic error but would appreciate any help you guys have! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm unable to trace the Plate entitled "MBR527D" within results

That's because it's not (directly) in it. `results` is an array, which has an object as first element, which has a property named `"plate"` which has the desired value:

```
"results": [{"plate": "MBR527D",
```

> ```
> trace(ThePlate.results.plate);
> ```

Try

```
trace(ThePlate.results[0].plate);
```

instead.